# Why my s3 bucket has list/read/write open to public and how to fix it

Tags: amazon-s3

I just started my AWS learning, here is my first s3 bucket:

[image]

You can see I have it open to public for READ only, on the same page on the right

[image]

Alright, I accept that risk, it is only READ.

However, in the bucket, after only a few hours, I see bunch of small files in my bucket:

[image]

If I open any of them, I see

[image]

If I click on the link I will see "Access Denied" in it:

[image]

Can anyone enlighten me what is going on there? I've just deleted most of them, will there be any cost incurred? I am on a free tier.

Comment: What's inside the files? It looks like you have setup something to log data to that bucket. The files are not public (as demonstrated by your attempt to open it). Checking that box does does not make the objects themselves public.

Comment: Thank you John. Your guess is right.

Answer (score 0):

I received the response from AWS support last week indicating the issue was caused by S3 logging was somehow enabled, that's why there are log files written into the bucket.

Issue is gone after logging is disabled.

Thanks.